# A plugin error was encountered when starting IDEA

Tags: function, exception

When opening IDEA, I encountered a plugin problem, prompting "File '**D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1\plugins\AppServersIntegration\lib\app-servers-integration.jar' contains invalid plugin descriptor** Plugin 'GlassFish' requires plugin 'com.intellij.javaee.app.servers.integration' to be installed
Plugin 'WildFly' requires plugin 'com.intellij.javaee.app.servers.integration' to be installed
Plugin 'Tomcat and TomEE' requires plugin 'com.intellij.javaee.app. servers.integration' to be installed"

Deleted app-servers-integration.jar from the folder, started IDEA and it still doesn't work!